# How to hide navigation bar immediately in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

My UIViewController is embed in a navigation controller:

[image]

I tried [setNavigationBarHidden:animated:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/setNavigationBarHidden:animated:) to hide notificationbar. It works but there are about 2 seconds delay. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

My usage is to add it in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
}
```

How to hide `navigationbar` immediately when screen is launched ?

Comment: Are you doing anything else in `viewDidLoad`.  I tried your code in a test app and there is no delay.

Comment: No, that's all in viewDidLoad(),  Do you think it is simulator cache issue ? Sometimes my screen will has old layout shown first and then transfer to new layout with 2 seconds delay.

Comment: I haven't ever seen anything like that.  My test was in the simulator.  Do you see the delay consistently.  Have you tried deleting the app from the simulator and re-installing? If you see it consistently have you tried the time-profile Instrument?

Comment: I tried reinstall and install it on both simulator and real device. It's the same. weird case.

Comment: Do you have any custom fonts in use?  What happens if you switch them back to the default font?

Comment: I think this issue is caused by I set "Launch Screen File" to the same storyboard file

Comment: You were probably seeing the launch screen, complete with navigation bar while the app launched and then the Nav bar was hidden once the app was launched.

Comment: We probably can't config the launch screen without navigation bar

Comment: Only by using a different storyboard for the launch that omits the navigation controller

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[According the official document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html):

> Every app must supply a launch file or at least one static image.

The delay is caused by the launch screen from the your main storyboard file. Don't set launch screen file to your `Main.storyboard` file.

In `Project settings > General -> App Icons and Launch Images -> Launch Screen File`:

[image]

Set it to another storyboard:

[image]

Answer (score 14):

hide the navgationBar when the ViewController init `ViewController.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)`

Comment: Sorry, could you explain more detail? Where should this code be placed?

Comment: try to hide the navgationBar in the initialize function`vc =[ [UIViewController alloc] init]; vc.navgationBar.hide = YES`

Answer (score 5):

A better way is to implement your code in viewWillLayoutSubviews(). It's a better approach if you use navigation or tapbar

**Swift 4** :

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
}
```

Answer (score 3):

#Add this line indside view did load method

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    }
```

##Otherwise directly do this from StoreyBoard

//Set Top Bar None

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGIsC.png

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Setting Top Bar to None will do nothing on runtime as this option is part of the simulated metrics. This only simulates the rendering in interface builder.

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
}
```

Comment: For future users. I have had similar issue but from another side. I have main view without Navigation bar and second view with navigation bar. When I return back from second view to main view I expect don't see navigation bar but it visible about 2 seconds. The fix of my issue was this answer. Need to add WillDisappear to second Viewcontroller file. Then when I return to main screen I don't see navigation bar at all.

Answer (score 1):

You need to hide the UINavigationBar in viewDidLoad() Method

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**For swift 3:-**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    }
```